# Django AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'について

Tags: python, django

djangoのルーティングで、path()に独自の関数を指定して、そこでrequestを受け取って処理を加えてからクラスビューを呼び出したいと思っています。
下記ソースでurlにアクセスすると、エラーとなります。
やりたいこととしては、別関数でrequestを受け取りつつ関数内で、クラスビュー.as_view()がしたいです。
お助け願います。

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from . import views

app_name='test'

def aaa(request):
　　if request.user.i == 0:
        return 'urｌ'
    else:
        return views.TestListView.as_view() ←　"this is where the error happen."

urlpatterns = [
    path('', aaa, name='test'),
]
```

```
Internal Server Error: /alcohol/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 116, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 0):

`views.TestListView.as_view()`の戻り値は関数です。requestを引数にしてこれを呼ぶ必要があります。つまり

`return views.TestListView.as_view()(request)`

とすればいいでしょう。